# how to change the input value on blur?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having one link as 'Add more' which adds input element as many as I want. I want to call blur function on that.

Following html gets added while click on 'Add more' link:

```
<input required="" class="form-control js-validate-hoursToAdd timetoadd" step="0.01" name="calculations[settingIndex][hoursToAdd][calculationIndex]" type="number" value="">
```

Blur event works only for first element which is there in DOM by default. When I add new element, blur event doesn't get bind to the element.

Following is the javascript code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".timetoadd").blur(function(){
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
    });
)};
```

It is in separate file called as backend.js. I am using webpack to minify the file and it is included in html file.

How to do that? Please help me out.

Comment: Can you post your script?

Comment: Where's your JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) method on a *parent* element with an additional selector as the second argument:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
    $('<br/><input required="" class="form-control js-validate-hoursToAdd timetoadd" step="0.01" name="calculations[settingIndex][hoursToAdd][calculationIndex]" type="number" value="">').appendTo(document.body);
  });

  $(document.body).on('blur', '.timetoadd', function(){
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnAdd">Add more</button>
<br/><input required="" class="form-control js-validate-hoursToAdd timetoadd" step="0.01" name="calculations[settingIndex][hoursToAdd][calculationIndex]" type="number" value="">
```

Instead of `document.body`, you could also use any other parent that contains the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

By adding the html attribute `onblur` and some javascript...

```js
function myFunc(input) {
  input.value = 0;
}
```

```html
<input required="" class="form-control js-validate-hoursToAdd timetoadd" step="0.01" name="calculations[settingIndex][hoursToAdd][calculationIndex]" type="number" value="" onblur="myFunc(this)">
```

Comment: I tried this as well. It says undefined function. I am using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I've made for you. Do this for your input. It should work fine

```js
function GetValue(e){
    alert(e.target.value);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inputgroup">
   <input type="text" name="Dynamic_0" onblur="GetValue(event)">
   <input type="text" name="Dynamic_1" onblur="GetValue(event)">
   <input type="text" name="Dynamic_2" onblur="GetValue(event)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// find elements
var id = $("#id > div")
var id1 = $("#id1")

var input = $("input")
var inputCopy;
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function() {
  $('<input required="" class="form-control js-validate-hoursToAdd timetoadd" step="0.01" name="calculations[settingIndex][hoursToAdd][calculationIndex]" type="number" value=""><br>').appendTo(id);
  /* addMore(e.currentTarget, e.currentTarget.value);
  console.log('new input', e.currentTarget); */
})


$(document.body).on("blur", '.timetoadd', function() {
  this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
  inputCopy = input;
})

function addMore(e, value) {
  inputCopy = e.clone()
  id.prepend($(inputCopy));
}
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#id {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#id.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#id.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="id">
  <button>Add more</button>
  <div>
    <input required class="form-control js-validate-hoursToAdd timetoadd" step="0.01" name="calculations[settingIndex][hoursToAdd][calculationIndex]" type="number" value="">
  </div>

</div>
```

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/kutec/c4pvLoua/